# Deployed War file in GlassFish 3

Tags: glassfish-3

I have deployed a war file on a test server, and i want to know if it is possible to download the deployed War file in GlassFish installed on a linux centos 7 server?

Answer (score 0):

1. Upload your file to your Linux server.
2. open your Linux command Console / Terminal
3. use cd (Change Directory) command to change your directory where your .war (Java War ) file located in your server.
   ex: cd public_html/Projects/First/
4. Now Write Deploy Command in Your Terminal :

> /opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin --user admin --passwordfile /opt/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain-passwords deploy yourFileName.war